End fed half-wave dipole only measured 5 ohms
This is a bit unusual but I am trying to diy a simple high impedance antenna running in 2.45GHz, for some explorations in ultra-narrow band applications in WiFi. And I have heard in ham radio community, folks use end fed half dipole to design a high impedance antenna.
I cut a 6.1cm wire and soldered it onto the signal port of an SMA as my antenna. I calibrated my VNA and I measured the impedance. The VNA showed an impedance of 5+j60 ohms. A photo here is attached with my antenna and set up with the VNA.
I know the characteristics impedance of an sma is 50 ohms but looking at the connection with my 6cm wire it should still make a half wavelength dipole and the impedance at 2.45GHz should be high (supposedly).
Anything concept am I missing here?

The outside of the coax is part of the antenna and you get something like an (vertical) off-center fed sleeve dipole.

If your picture is the way you are testing it, I would agree with Raonoke; You need to choke the feedpoint of the antenna. On top of that, be aware of nearby reflective objects that could cause your impedance to drop.

If you short-circuit the SMA connector with a knife blade, just where the wire is soldered, do you see a nice short circuit on the Smith chart?  See this answer for some relevant suggestions.

Aside from checking the short mentioned by tomnexus, I shall add an RF choke to my antenna. So the calibration plane shall be the VNA->Coax->RF choke, and then I do the ECAL for calibration?

No... it's kind of redundant. I imagine the impedance of a half-wave of wire will be pretty high, no matter what's on the ground side of the connector. Usually for any sort SMA antenna tests, you will have a fairly large metal groundplane, so the rest of the cable isn't part of the circuit. What sort of RF choke would you use? If you're testing (say) a half wave dipole, perpendicular to the coax, then the best I can think of at this frequency is a large diameter quarter wave coaxial short built around the cable, open end near the connector. Ferrites and coils won't work.

thanks tomnexus. I am also not very clear about the purpose of using an RF choke but giving it a try to see how that works out. I have done several microstrip planar antennas at similar frequencies and never needed any RF choke. For VNA testing they would be antenna + SMA similar to the setup up and the results were close to prediction. I also simulated a simple half-wave dipole with a feed point at the end using MATLAB, and the simulation also gave a near 0 ohms resistance and a large(2500 ohms) reactance. So now I suspect there is some theory I am missing about the end-fed dipole.

A half wave dipole is fed in the middle, it should be ~70 ohms and the reactance crosses thorough zero. To physically connect this to a network analyser you need a choke or something. Fed at the end, its an efhw again (it still needs a counterpoise, otherwise what's the other half of the feed connected to... it's an open circuit...).

I see, so for an end-fed antenna, since the excitation is close to both the antenna and the coax, it is treating the antenna + the coax as a whole system. I have a 1:1 balun in hand and I am thinking: VNA -> Coax -> Balun -> SMA -> Antenna. The single-ended side will connect to the coax, and the differential-ended side to the SMA: one at the signal and the other at the ground. Additionally, I am soldering a counterpoise (another piece of wire) at the ground of the SMA. Would this configuration make sense?
And for measurement, should my calibration plane be after the balun and before the SMA?

Yes as you say, everything is part of the antenna system. But a large groundplane will hide the coax and VNA from the antenna. If the goal here is to compare measurement to simulation, then I recommend simulating the antenna fed against a (infinite) ground plane, and then building and measuring it like this too. I'm not sure what kind of balun you have at 2.4 GHz, but it won't perfectly "break" the coax, and will have some length beyond the magic part in the middle. This is all hard to simulate, so its effect in the measured case will be quite unpredictable.

You could also try modelling the coax etc as a long wire, say 10 or 20 wl, with a feed 0.5 wl from the end. This is most similar to the photo you posted above. But you'll get some current all down the wire, which means your simulation deviates from reality, possibly in a significant way, and you won't get the answer you want.

My money would still be on the calibration being wrong, or the reference plane being somewhere you don't expect. When you're back in the lab, short the SMA and see how that looks. Then, two more important tests to do every time you test an antenna: 1. Run your hand down the coax from the antenna to the VNA. If the trace moves, the coax is part of the antenna. 2. Wave the antenna around a bit, to see how much of the reflected power comes from the antenna alone, and how much from the environment. . When you've tried all this, please update your question and I'll consolidate this into an answer.
